# AsyncOperation using Console or WindowsService

Tags: c#, asynchronous

How do I use AsyncOperation within a Console or Windows Servie project?

This approach works using windows forms but fails for console and service:

```
static void Bla2(object o)
{
    //e.g. 10 but should be the same as mainId
    //Works when using Windows Forms
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
}

static void Bla(object o)
{
    int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;  //e.g. 9 => always different from mainId

    AsyncOperation asyncOp = (AsyncOperation)o;
    asyncOp.Post(Bla2, null);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int mainId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;  //e.g. 8
    AsyncOperation asyncOp = AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation(null);

    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Bla));
    t.Start(asyncOp);

    ...
}
```

A similar question was posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494733/asyncoperation-to-raise-events-specially-in-class-libraries
but did not get any answers.

What am I doing wrong?

Am I missing sth?

Comment: what .net framework version are you trying to target?

Comment: I'm using .Net4 but will switch to 4.6 soon

Answer (score 0):

Based on the dot net target version that you are using, i would recommend using async/await.  it is a simple and easy way to multithread out your applications, but keep in mind race conditions and all other pitfalls of multi-threading development.

```
static task<int> async Bla2Async(object o)
{
    return await WebClient.PostToWebAPIAsync(o);//Log time to complete. returns response code(int) from http response
}

static void Bla(object o)
{
    var response = Bla2Async(o);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Bla(new object());


    ...
}
```

this is outlined on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.140).aspx).  It outlines all the details of how async/await keywords work.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control of the threading. Just posted a simplified version. In fact I'm using WCF.  Bla2(object o) should be executed in the main thread (That's the one that created my WCF DuplexChannelFactory)